# "Te va (a) encantar" - is "a" necessary?

Tags: sintaxis, tiempos-verbales, futuro

Is the "a" necessary when using ["ir a" to convey future meaning](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/319/ir-a-infinitive-vs-future-tense)?

Google gives 17m results for "[te va a encantar](http://google.com/search?q=%22te+va+a+encantar%22)" but also 1.5m for "[te va encantar](http://google.com/search?q=%22te+va+encantar%22)".  Does this rule vary according to formality?

Comment: i've changed the "future tense" tag to just "future" so we can use it also with "ir a" or in combination with "verb tense" like here

Answer (score 12):

"Te va encantar" is gramatically incorrect. I had never heard it before, at least in Spain. The sentence should be:

> Te va a encantar

as it has a future meaning

> Ir a + infinitive = going to + infinitive

Probably it's a mistake made because we link the words when speaking so "te va a encantar" would be pronounced as "te va-a encantar", we say it "va-a" with a short pause between both "a" or even with a long "a". As we usually speak quickly some people may have understood it wrongly and the error could have spread.

In this [link](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=ir%28se%29) RAE speaks about it

> 1. ir a + infinitivo. Perífrasis verbal que indica que la acción designada por el infinitivo se va a producir en un futuro más o menos
>      inmediato: «Vas a tener miles de problemas» (Gamboa Páginas [Col.
>      1998]); muy a menudo implica propósito o intención por parte del
>      sujeto: «Te voy a leer una carta de mi padre» (Jodorowsky Pájaro
>      [Chile 1992]); a veces se emplea con finalidad exhortativa: «Para
>      empezar, vas a sentarte como un niño bueno» (Vilalta Nada [Méx.
>      1975]); en ocasiones se emplea, especialmente en pasado, para indicar
>      que lo expresado por el infinitivo es un hecho inesperado o
>      inoportuno: El asunto fue a salir por donde menos se esperaba. **En
>      ningún caso debe suprimirse, en el habla culta, la preposición a:**
>      «Pero ¿se lo vas plantear ya?» (FnGómez Bicicletas [Esp. 1982]); Vamos
>      hablar del asunto.

as the text says: the preposition "a" mustn't be suppressed .

Comment: +1 When speaking quickly, *te va a encantar* and *te va encantar* sound almost identical.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this construction is grammatical in some of the other Romance languages. I know I'm familiar with it but can't recall if it's from the other languages or maybe I heard it in Spanish in Central America somewhere. I'd say it's a natural change for some branches of Romance that is accepted in some but not in Spanish.

Comment: @hippietrail: It is grammatical indeed in Galician. "Vaiche encantar" ("te va a encantar") means literally "te va encantar", without the "a".