# Which tenses of "ír" are permissible in the "ir a infinitive" construction?

Tags: futuro

For expressing an intention for the future (I am going to...) of course we use the construction: ir (conjugated) + a + infinitive.
I have seen and used the present and imperfect tenses for this purpose--
Voy a comprar...
Ibas a comprar... etc.
Today a teacher told me that one could also use the simple future of ir in the "ir a" construction, eg.  iré a comprar...  This seemed completely weird to me and redundant; I asked her: Why wouldn't I just say Compraré...?
So my question is: Which tenses of "ír" are permissible in the "ir + a + infinitive" construction?  Thank you

Comment: Check [this link](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/319/ir-a-infinitive-vs-future-tense). In short, all tenses of "ír" are permissible.

Comment: Both _Compraré un libro_ and _Voy a comprar un libro_ means that you are going to buy a book in the future. Situations: 
You're outside with a friend of you and then you see a guy in a great car, you may think _algún día compraré uno_, _algún día voy a comprar uno_.
You are in your house and in the need carrots, you would say:
_ya vuelvo, voy a comprar zanahorias_ or _ya vuelvo, compraré zanahorias_. For the "ir a" construction, guifa's answer is right.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the *ir a [inf]* construction in any tense (iba/fui/iré a nadar), mood (que vaya/fuera/fuese/fuere a nadar) or even aspect (ha ido / está yendo a nadar), although some are certainly vastly more common than others.

While using it in the indicative future might seem redundant, it can express an ordering of future events, effectively like the difference between simple preterite and pluperfect.

That said, just because you have *ir a [inf]* doesn't mean you're indicating an future action. Especially in some forms (future, preterite) and always for others (imperative/exhortative subjunctive), it's not the periphrastic future construction, but rather plain *ir* with a prepositional phrase indicating purpose or intent (notice how *Vete/andate/idos/váya(n)se **a** nadar* works).